# using a textbox more than once in c#

Tags: c#, sockets

here is a small client GUI program written in c#. The idea is: first the client will send an id (typed in the textbox)to server(pressing the check button), the server will check that id and if it's valid the server will return a value 0 otherwise -1. Now if the return value is -1, then the client will again take an input in the checkbox and send it to the server for another check(by pressing the check button). This process will go on until the client receives a 0 from the server. But, In my code, when I make an invalid input in the textbox, it hangs as well as the check button. So, I can't repeat the proces of sending a valid id to server. Here is my sample client code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
 using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class AsyncTcpClient:Form
{

    private TextBox newText;
    private Button check;
    public  TcpClient tcpClient;


   NetworkStream ns;
    StreamReader sr;
    StreamWriter sw;  
    string data;

public AsyncTcpClient()
{

    Size = new Size(400, 380);

    newText = new TextBox();
    newText.Parent = this;
    newText.Size = new Size(200, 2 * Font.Height);
    newText.Location = new Point(10, 55);

    check = new Button();
     check.Parent = this;
     check.Text = "checkID";
     check.Location = new Point(295, 52);
     check.Size = new Size(6 * Font.Height, 2 * Font.Height);
     check.Click += new EventHandler(checkOnClick);

    }


void checkOnClick(object obj, EventArgs ea)
{
    tcpClient = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 1234);
     ns = tcpClient.GetStream();
     sr = new StreamReader(ns);
     sw = new StreamWriter(ns);
    send:
    //sending ID
    sw.WriteLine(newText.Text);
    sw.Flush();
    //receiving validity of ID
    data = sr.ReadLine();
    int validid = int.Parse(data);
    if (validid == 0)
    {            
        newText.Text="Valid data";
        check.Enabled = false;          
    }
    else
    {                        
        //sending ID again            
        goto send;
    }
}

[STAThread]
public static void Main()
{

    Application.Run(new AsyncTcpClient());
}
}
```

How will I continuously check my id is valid or not?

Comment: If you "GOTO" without leaving your user the time to write a new text you will loop forever here

Comment: what is the solution then? @Steve

Comment: using Goto looks very bad

Comment: Can you please give me a solution? @Viru

Comment: Did you try to do nothing in else block (or show a message to user, ex: wrong input etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

You should simply clear the textbox content and write a warning to your user and wait the he/she writes a new id

```
void checkOnClick(object obj, EventArgs ea)
{
    tcpClient = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 1234);
    ns = tcpClient.GetStream();
    sr = new StreamReader(ns);
    sw = new StreamWriter(ns);
    //sending ID
    sw.WriteLine(newText.Text);
    sw.Flush();
    //receiving validity of ID
    data = sr.ReadLine();
    int validid = int.Parse(data);
    if (validid == 0)
    {            
        newText.Text="Valid data";
        check.Enabled = false;          
    }
    else
    {                        
        newText.Text="Invalid data. Please retry";       
        // Now the code will exit and your user could retry
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First remove GOTO statement then move your tcp Connection in constructor in this way your connection is persistent (you are avoiding tcp three way handshake every time you click button) then use label to display error message and wait for user to enter valid data before proceeding

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
 using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class AsyncTcpClient:Form
{

    private TextBox newText;
    private Button check;
    private Label errorMessage;
    public  TcpClient tcpClient;


   NetworkStream ns;
    StreamReader sr;
    StreamWriter sw;  
    string data;

public AsyncTcpClient()
{
tcpClient = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 1234);
     ns = tcpClient.GetStream();
    Size = new Size(400, 380);

    newText = new TextBox();
    newText.Parent = this;
    newText.Size = new Size(200, 2 * Font.Height);
    newText.Location = new Point(10, 55);

    errorMessage = new Label();
    errorMessage.Parent = this;
     errorMessage.Size = new Size(200, 2 * Font.Height);
    errorMessage.Location = new Point(20, 55);   

    check = new Button();
     check.Parent = this;
     check.Text = "checkID";
     check.Location = new Point(295, 52);
     check.Size = new Size(6 * Font.Height, 2 * Font.Height);
     check.Click += new EventHandler(checkOnClick);

    }


void checkOnClick(object obj, EventArgs ea)
{

     using(sr = new StreamReader(ns))
{
     using(sw = new StreamWriter(ns))
    {
    //sending ID
    sw.WriteLine(newText.Text);
    sw.Flush();
    //receiving validity of ID
    data = sr.ReadLine();
    int validid = int.Parse(data);
    if (validid == 0)
    {            
        newText.Text="Valid data";
        check.Enabled = false;          
    }
    else
    {                        
   errorMessage.Text="InValid data enter again";   
    }
}
}
}

[STAThread]
public static void Main()
{

    Application.Run(new AsyncTcpClient());
}
}
```